# Email Regex is causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, email

Can anybody please have a look at 
https://regex101.com/r/ApWCG0/1 
and correct the regex so that it doesn't give timeout or doesn't cause infinite loop ? 
I have been testing it in nodejs and getting an infinite loop and getting in timeout in Regex testing websites.
I have been searching for it for a while on stackoverflow and other websites but couldn't find it. Sorry, if this thread has a duplicate.

my email regex is 
`[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+`

Hope somebody get through this.

*Update*: 
`[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]{2,64}@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,64}\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{2,64}` 
This is covering most cases. I am just restricting the number of characters.

Comment: just go here: http://emailregex.com/

Comment: @garglblarg ok, I am watching that, but could you explain why is that giving timeout or infinite loop ?

Comment: @garglblarg I tried [http://emailregex.com/email-extractor-tool/](http://emailregex.com/email-extractor-tool/) website with the same content to extract emails from, but this goes in infinite loop. Any idea what would work in this case ?

Comment: in this case i suspect that it's not a wrong regex but invalid input _or_ it's not really an infinite loop but just taking very very long which would look the same, i dunno.

Comment: ok, I got you, I will see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your regular expression and found out that if we pass single word[**which has extremely high character length**] then regular expression fail to check and give timeout error.

E.g: https://regex101.com/r/sjvQ7Z/1

And when I removed that word from your test string then your expresion is working fine.

E.g: https://regex101.com/r/lszdaL/1

Comment: I agree with you sir. but I don't have any control over the input so came up with this `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]{2,64}@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,64}\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{2,64}`. The points you have mentioned are the exact words for the problem. I appreciate that. It helped!

Answer (score 0):

You experienced catastrophic backtracking because of the Chat Data dump that contained **943k** characters. Just remove it and it'll work fine.

Comment: Ok, I think, backtracking is the technical definition of the problem. thanks for your input.